# How to Use Lightning Design System in LWR?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwr, lwr-oss

I am creating a new Lightning Web Runtime app. I chose the Single Page App & TypeScript support options when using the CLI to initially create the app with the `npm init lwr` command.

I was able to add the lightning-base-components npm package and it's working just fine. But when I try to add SLDS, the styles do not show up for me.

I first installed both @salesforce-ux/design-system and @lwc/synthetic-shadow since SLDS requires synthetic shadow as a dependency when being used off-platform.

I then created my index.html file, linking to the SLDS stylesheet in the head tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>My LWR App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="$sldsDir/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <!-- triple braces prevents HTML escaping -->
  {{{body}}} {{{lwr_resources}}}
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, I updated my LWR.config.json file:

```
{
    "lwc": { "modules": [
        { "dir": "$rootDir/src/modules" }, 
        { "npm": "lightning-base-components" }
    ] },
    "bundleConfig": { "exclude": [
        "lwc", 
        "lwr/navigation", 
        "@lwc/synthetic-shadow"
    ] },
    "layoutsDir": "$rootDir/src/modules",
    "assets": [
        {
            "alias": "sldsDir",
            "dir": "$rootDir/node_modules/@salesforce-ux/design-system/assets",
            "urlPath": "/slds"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "id": "example",
            "path": "/",
            "rootComponent": "example/app",
            "layoutTemplate": "$layoutsDir/index.html"
        }
    ]
}
```

At this point, everything works except SLDS. I have some SLDS classes on a few base components in my app module, but when the module loads, the styles do not show up because synthetic-shadow is still disabled. I can see from 'view source' in the browser that shadow-root is still open.

I'm at a loss as there is no index.js to use the `import '@lwc/synthetic-shadow';` statement and the SLDS docs don't even mention LWR.

How do I force LWR to use the synthetic shadow DOM instead of the native DOM provided by the browser so that my global styles will be applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LWR.config.json file
add  "syntheticShadow": true

```
 "routes": [
        {
            "id": "slds-base",
            "path": "/",
            "rootComponent": "example/app",
            "layoutTemplate": "$layoutsDir/main.html",
            "bootstrap": {
                "syntheticShadow": true
            }
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Truth be told, SLDS needs to be updated for shadow DOM support. LWC relies on it heavily and you're really losing a lot of the features by using the synthetic shadow.

It doesn't work for everything, but here's my approach:

Create an extension of LightningElement like so:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export class LightningElementSlds extends LightningElement {

    constructor() {
        super();

        return this;
    }
}
```

Anywhere you would normally use Lightning LightningElementSlds instead. Next load the CSS. I prefer to roll my own LoadCss method outlined below:

```
export default function LoadCss(path, scope) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const style = document.createElement('link');
        style.href = path;
        style.rel = 'stylesheet';

        style.onload = () => {
            resolve(style);
        };
        style.onerror = (e) => {
            console.error('Unable to load', path, e);
        };

        if (scope) {
            scope.template.appendChild(style);
        } else {
            document.querySelector('head').appendChild(style);
        }
    });
}
```

I like the added await I added in for other utils. Anyway, assuming you made this in 'utils/css' update LightningElementSlds like so:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import LoadCSS from 'utils/css';

export class LightningElementSlds extends LightningElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        LoadCSS(
            '/lib/slds/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css',
            this
        );

        return this;
    }
}
```

This will load the SLDS stylesheet in every Shadow DOM element. If you're curious about my path assignment, I'm requiring @salesforce-ux/design-system in my package.json and assigning it to an asset directory in lwr.json:

```
...
assets: [
{
    "alias": "sldsStyles",
    "dir": "$rootDir/node_modules/@salesforce-ux/design-system/assets",
    "urlPath": "/lib/slds"
  }
]
...
```

You will need to use a layout and attach it to the index.html for the body styles. For your routes, add `"layoutTemplate": "$layoutsDir/index.html"` and add the same link to the stylesheet there in the .

#### Benefits

Why use this over Synthetic DOM? Simply put, it keeps your styles corralled. I've been really enjoying just adding tag selectors in my css stylesheets OR overriding simple .slds-* classes in individual modules. Using third party libraries no longer breaks anything else on sites either. If I need to use some wacky, offbeat module due to some insane client/coworker demand it simply cannot break the system. It's clear that Synthetic Shadow is on its way out.

The only bits of SLDS that is not compatible with this method are when there are nested selectors. Tables are a bit tricky as they need to live in the same module. My initial inclination would be to make modules for tableRow and tableCell, but in SLDS they all cascade from .slds-table. Minor inconvenience that just requires a bit of module tweaking.

**Edit:** Don't reject() inside the LoadCSS Promise. Client-side routing will stop loading css if you're quickly navigating around the site. These are mostly "soft" errors as they are user initiated. I still choose to log them to spot any issues, but rejecting them outright can prevent the app from rendering as it's a constructor error in the LightingElement itself.