# Issue with building SPA (Single Page Application) on LWR (Lightning Web Runtime) with LWC base components

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, lwr, lightning-web-runtime

I'm building a Single Page Application on LWR by utilising Base Lightning Web Components, I followed following threads to understand the process and all-

- [Use Base Lightning Web Components with LWR on Node.js](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwr/guide/lwr-lwc.html)
- [Use Salesforce Lightning Design System with LWR on Node.js](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwr/guide/lwr-slds.html)

But it didn't work for me, Here is my project details:

###### Project Structure

[image]

###### package.json file

```
{
  "name": "lwr-my-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node ./scripts/copy-slds.mjs",
    "clean": "rm -rf __lwr_cache__",
    "dev": "lwr serve",
    "start": "lwr serve --mode prod",
    "start:compat": "lwr serve --mode compat",
    "start:prod-compat": "lwr serve --mode prod-compat"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@salesforce-ux/design-system": "^2.17.5",
    "cpx": "^1.5.0",
    "lightning-base-components": "^1.15.4-alpha",
    "lwc": "2.17.0",
    "lwr": "0.7.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.15.4 <19"
  }
}
```

###### lwr.config.json file

```
{
    "lwc": { "modules": [{ "dir": "$rootDir/src/modules" },{ "npm": "lightning-base-components" }] },
    "routes": [
        {
            "id": "example",
            "path": "/",
            "rootComponent": "example/app",
            "bootstrap": {
                "syntheticShadow": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

###### app.html and app.js

```
<!-- app.html -->
<template>
    <main>
        <img src="public/assets/recipes-logo.png" alt="logo" />
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </main>
    <lightning-card  title="Hello">
        <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">Card Body here</p>
        <p slot="footer">Card Footer</p>
    </lightning-card>
</template>


// app.js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class HelloWorldApp extends LightningElement {}
```

Currently this is what i see when I load the URL (http://localhost:3000/) in browser:
[image]

As you can see the base LWC components are not loaded, if you want to try out and setup the sample project, please follow this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwr/guide/lwr-get-started.html)

If you want to clone my project and then directly work on that, [click here](https://github.com/nps6211/Sample-LWR-App)

Comment: You can see the card is present, but the **styling** is missing. Try: [How to Use Lightning Design System in LWR?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/371650/2984).

Comment: @sfdcfox, I checked that thread before, unfortunetly I didn't get one part from this question, why we need to add `layoutTemplate` in lwr.config.json. It is not a staticSite, it is SPA, so if we need to add this `layoutTemplate` like the one which is shown in the referenced question, where should I add it and second what should I write, that is confusing. 

Also another possibility which I see here is may be something is not referenced properly, when I use @track or @wire in the js file, It throws error on load and page is blank.

Comment: @sfdcfox, I tried rebuilding of the whole project, which resolve that blank page error but it seems something off with the lightning-base-component [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightning-base-components), When I use `lightning-input` it doesn't compile and throw some reference error. Any idea about that or known limitation. I checked with some other base components and it works.

Comment: I build a package a while ago, but I haven't used lwr recently, so I'm not sure what the syntax for it today is. If I find a recent example, I'll let you know.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, also let me share the codebase, that will help someone to understand and try out it.

Comment: Sure, send me a link, I'll be happy to clone and take a look.

Comment: @sfdcfox, You can clone the code from [here](https://github.com/nps6211/Sample-LWR-App) and install the required packages and try to run.

Comment: Looks like you made it work, what about answering to your own question to help others ?

Comment: @FabienTaillon, I updated the question with my findings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve the LWC base components styling issue with LWR SPA. Following things need to add in the SPA project to enable LWC component styling.

Refer [Use Salesforce Lightning Design System with LWR on Node.js](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwr/guide/lwr-slds.html) for more details about this.

In summary following instructions you can perform:

1. Add a layout template html file in your SPA project, LWR documentation is not very clear about that, also their boilerplate example doesn't include it as well. So create a `main.html` file and place it in your `src\layouts` location.

###### main.html

```
<!-- src/layouts/main.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover" />
        <title>LWR + SLDS Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="$assetsDir/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        {{{body}}} {{{lwr_resources}}}
    </body>
</html>
```

2. Update your `lwr.config.json` to include the path for the layout template which you have defined.

###### lwr.config.json

```
{
    "lwc": { "modules": [{ "dir": "$rootDir/src/modules" },{ "npm": "lightning-base-components" }] },
    "assets": [
        {
            "alias": "assetsDir",
            "dir": "$rootDir/node_modules/@salesforce-ux/design-system/assets",
            "urlPath": "/assets"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "id": "example",
            "path": "/",
            "rootComponent": "example/app",
            "layoutTemplate": "$layoutsDir/main.html",
            "bootstrap": {
                "syntheticShadow": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I was able to run the application and LWC base component styling was also applied but then there was some other issue with the LWC base components, whenever I use `<lightning-input>` tag it throws  a run-time exception, I created an another bug for that purpose and referenced it here.

[Issue with using LWC base components <lightning-input> with the LWR Single Page Application](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/385535/issue-with-using-lwc-base-components-lightning-input-with-the-lwr-single-page)