# Issue with using LWC base components <lightning-input> with the LWR Single Page Application

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, lwr, lightning-web-runtime

I've started with a Single Page Application on LWR, Able to run the app with Lightning design system and LWC base component package.
When I use `<lightning-input>` tag in my component js, it breaks the compilation and when I tried to load the application I see following error on terminal along with on browser I see blank page with error on console. Also same thing happens when I tried to use any onchange event like on any of the form element fields, like textarea, checkbox etc.

**Error details (copied from Terminal):**

```
Running LWR v0.7.3 at: http://localhost:3000 | mode: dev
Watching:  D:\SFDC Dev\LWR\lwr-new\lwr-project\src\layouts\main.html
Watching:  D:\SFDC Dev\LWR\lwr-new\lwr-project\src\modules\example\app\app.js
Watching:  D:\SFDC Dev\LWR\lwr-new\lwr-project\src\modules\example\app\app.html
Watching:  D:\SFDC Dev\LWR\lwr-new\lwr-project\src\modules\example\app\app.css
Error: Transform failed with 1 error:
<stdin>:5:191: error: Syntax error "t"
    at failureErrorWithLog (D:\SFDC Dev\LWR\lwr-new\lwr-project\node_modules\@lwrjs\compiler\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1224:15)
    at D:\SFDC Dev\LWR\lwr-new\lwr-project\node_modules\@lwrjs\compiler\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1072:33
    at D:\SFDC Dev\LWR\lwr-new\lwr-project\node_modules\@lwrjs\compiler\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:568:9
    at handleIncomingPacket (D:\SFDC Dev\LWR\lwr-new\lwr-project\node_modules\@lwrjs\compiler\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:657:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (D:\SFDC Dev\LWR\lwr-new\lwr-project\node_modules\@lwrjs\compiler\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:535:7)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
  errors: [
    {
      detail: undefined,
      location: [Object],
      notes: [],
      text: 'Syntax error "t"'
    }
  ],
  warnings: []
}
```

**Error screenshot from Browser (localhost:3000)**
[image]

##### Steps to Reproduce

- Clone the project boilerplate from [here](https://github.com/nps6211/Sample-LWR-App), I've created this project from my local system.
- setup the project directory and navigate to it from command line.
- Run the following command `npm install` and `npm dev run` which will run the local server on the `localhost:3000`
- Open the browser and Navigate to the `localhost:3000` see the error message on the console and terminal as mentioned.
- Now for a moment remove the `<lightning-input>` tag from the component js `/src/modules/example/app/app.html` and run the server again, see the error is gone.

##### Code Snippet

**`lwr.config.json`**

```
{
    "lwc": { "modules": [{ "dir": "$rootDir/src/modules" },{ "npm": "lightning-base-components" }] },
    "assets": [
        {
            "alias": "assetsDir",
            "dir": "$rootDir/node_modules/@salesforce-ux/design-system/assets",
            "urlPath": "/assets"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "id": "example",
            "path": "/",
            "rootComponent": "example/app",
            "layoutTemplate": "$layoutsDir/main.html",
            "bootstrap": {
                "syntheticShadow": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**`package.json`**

```
{
  "name": "lwr-project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf __lwr_cache__",
    "dev": "lwr serve",
    "start": "lwr serve --mode prod",
    "start:compat": "lwr serve --mode compat",
    "start:prod-compat": "lwr serve --mode prod-compat"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@salesforce-ux/design-system": "^2.17.5",
    "lightning-base-components": "^1.15.4-alpha",
    "lwc": "2.17.0",
    "lwr": "0.7.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.15.4 <19"
  }
}
```

**Component HTML and JS**

```
<!-- app.html -->
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <lightning-layout horizontal-align="center">
            <lightning-layout-item padding="around-medium">
                <div class="slds-text-heading_large">Sample LWC App</div>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
        <lightning-layout horizontal-align="center">
            <lightning-layout-item padding="around-medium">
                <lightning-input onchange={handleOnChange} value={inputVal} label="Enter Name"></lightning-input>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item padding="around-medium">
                <lightning-button label="Click Me!" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
        <lightning-layout horizontal-align="center">
            <lightning-layout-item padding="around-medium"><div>Entered Value: {inputVal}</div></lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
    </div>
</template>


// app.js
import {track,LightningElement} from 'lwc';
export default class HelloWorldApp extends LightningElement {
    @track inputVal = 'Default text';

    handleOnChnage(event){
        this.inputVal = event.target.value;
    }

    handleClick(event){
        this.inputVal = 'Changed By Click';
    }

    connectedCallback(){
        //console.log('In connected callback');
    }

    renderedCallback(){
        //console.log('In rendered callback');
    }
}
```

#### Browsers Affected

All browsers, tested with Chrome, Mozilla, Edge

#### Version

- Node Version: v18.9.0
- OS: Windows 10
- NPM: 6.14.11
- @salesforce-ux/design-system- 2.18.1
- lightning-base-components- 1.15.4-alpha
- lwc- 2.17.0
- lwr- 0.7.3

**I've also raised this issue on the LWC Git Project, here is the link to the [issue](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/issues/2993).**

Comment: I updated the node version to latest one, so I would suggest whoever building the package, please use latest node version or specifically  `>=14.18.2`