# LWC on Heroku with lightning design system and lightning base components

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, heroku

I want to deploy a lwc to heroku and use the lightning desing system and lightning base components. I tried a lot of different approaches I found online but non of them worked. As described [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/371650/how-to-use-lightning-design-system-in-lwr) at least it worked on my local machine but not on heroku.

Another approach I tried is this one (on heroku I still get 503 service unavailable):

Would be awesome if there is someone who can help with the code below or who can forward me to a project structure wich is working for heroku.

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "sandboxtest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./src/server.js",
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "copyAssets": "node scripts/copyAssets.js",
    "postinstall": "node scripts/copyAssets.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@lwc/rollup-plugin": "^2.36.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-replace": "^5.0.2",
    "@salesforce-ux/design-system": "^2.20.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "fs-extra": "^11.1.0",
    "lightning-base-components": "^1.17.2-alpha",
    "lwc": "2.17.0",
    "rollup": "^2.37.1"
  }
}
```

**rollup.config.js**

```js
const path = require("path");
const lwcRollupPlugin = require("@lwc/rollup-plugin");
const replace = require("@rollup/plugin-replace");

const input = path.resolve(__dirname, "src/app.js");
const outputDir = path.resolve(__dirname, "public");

module.exports = {
  input,
  output: {
    dir: path.join(outputDir, "app.js"),
    format: "esm"
  },
  plugins: [
    lwcRollupPlugin({
      modules: [
        { npm: "@salesforce-ux/design-system" },
        { npm: "lightning-base-components" }
      ]
    }),
    replace({
      "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    })
  ].filter(Boolean),
  watch: {
    exclude: ["node_modules/**"]
  }
};
```

**lwc.config.json**

```js
{
  "lwc": {
    "modules": [
      { "dir": "$rootDir/src/modules" },
      { "npm": "lightning-base-components" }
    ]
  },
  "routes": [
    {
      "id": "foo",
      "path": "/",
      "rootComponent": "foo/app",
      "layoutTemplate": "./public/index.html",
      "bootstrap": {
        "syntheticShadow": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**server.js**

```js
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const rollup = require("rollup");
const config = require("../rollup.config");


app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  return res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../public/index.html"));
});

app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
);

(async () => {
  const watcher = await rollup.watch(config);
  watcher.on('event', (event) => {
    if (event.code === 'START') {
      console.log('Compiling...');
    }
    if (event.code === "END") {
      console.log('Done!');
    }
  });
})();
```

**app.js**

```js
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import '@lwc/synthetic-shadow';
import FooApp from 'foo/app';


document
    .querySelector('#main')
    .appendChild(createElement('foo-app', { is: FooApp }))
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"
    />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css"
    />
    <title>LWC APP!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="/app.js/app.js" type="module"></script>
</html>
```

**Procfile**

```
web: node ./src/server.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing deploying this to Heroku is probably due to the hard-coded HTTP port (3000) that is instead randomly chosen by Heroku and can be retrieved via the environment variable **PORT**.

In **server.js** you could use something like `const port = process.env.PORT || 3000` instead of `const port = 3000;`

This article may help you as well: [Getting Started on Heroku with Node.js](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs)